# Httpd - Loadbalancing Response Time Increases When a Worker Downs

Tags: apache, tomcat, web, load-balancing, mod-jk

I set up a load-balance structure using Apache Tomcat, httpd using mod_jk module.

I set 3 lb-workers for 3 Tomcat instances, with the following properties:

```
worker.list=balancer,status

worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.port=8011
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.retries=2
worker.worker1.reply_timeout=1000
worker.worker1.ping_timeout=2000 

worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.port=8012
worker.worker2.host=localhost
worker.worker2.retries=2
worker.worker2.reply_timeout=1000 
worker.worker2.ping_timeout=2000

worker.worker3.type=ajp13
worker.worker3.port=8013
worker.worker3.host=localhost
worker.worker3.retries=2
worker.worker3.reply_timeout=1000 
worker.worker3.ping_timeout=2000


worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2,worker3

worker.status.type=status
```

It works fine, directs the requests equally to the workers as I want. However, when I stop one of the instances, response times are suddenly increases for about 10-15 secs like the following response time data:

```
TIME: 1006 msecs
TIME: 1007 msecs
TIME: 1006 msecs
TIME: 1022 msecs
TIME: 1030 msecs
TIME: 1000 msecs
TIME: 1015 msecs
TIME: 1031 msecs
TIME: 2011 msecs
TIME: 1015 msecs
TIME: 1015 msecs
TIME: 1030 msecs
TIME: 999 msecs
```

And then it comes to normal

```
 TIME: 0 msecs
 TIME: 0 msecs
 TIME: 0 msecs
 TIME: 0 msecs
 TIME: 0 msecs
 TIME: 0 msecs
```

Why are the response times of all workers affected ?

Why is this happening ? Shouldn't it switch the new requests to available workers after it notices one of them is down ? Why it continues to direct incoming requests to the broken worker ?

Should I change the worker properties ?

Comment: please check httpd and mod_jk log files. There may be many reasons but log will help us to narrow down your question

Comment: Seems the JSESSIONID jvmroute suffix is not being changed first time the request is being handled by other worker. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Bind_session_after_crash_to_failover_node

Comment: Thanks fo the answer. @jlumietu , should I configure Tomcat server rather than Httpd or mod_jk ? Can you please give me a bit detail ? Thanks

Comment: You should check if your JSESSIONID cookie jvmroute suffix changes after being redirected to another Tomcat when the one you opened session to goes down. So, if you open session and you get `.worker1` suffix, then stop that worker and do something in the webapp, in order to being redirected to worker2 or worker3. After receiving the server response, your cookie should have been changed from suffix `.worker1` to `.worker(2|3)`. If it remains as worker1, it means that at every request the mod_jk must redirect you to worker1 which is down, causing such a big response time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added jvmRoute="worker1", jvmRoute="worker2" and jvmRoute="worker3" suffix for all my tomcat server.xmls <Engine> tag. Result is same. It still gives such big response times for at least 15 secs when one of the instances are down. What am I doing wrong ?